# XSLT code produce unwanted " and \ in the output

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have used below xslt code to get an outout.

```
<users>
  <xsl:text>[</xsl:text>
  <xsl:for-each select="ds:user_id">
  <xsl:if test="position() != 1">
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
  </xsl:if>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:for-each>
  <xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
</users>
```

But I am getting below output for above code,

`"users": "[\"1\"]"`

But my expected output was below,

`"users": ["1"]`

How can I get my expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say you were using the "json" output method by mistake. But as Michael says, you need to post a complete example, not just a fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create JSON "by hand", use output method "text". If you want the system to create JSON for you, use output method "json".